# Cannot set social links in Wordpress

Tags: wordpress

I am new to Wordpress and I want to set up my personal website, I am using a Theme and there is a  part says as the image I attached, I want to find the social links part but I failed, I reference some videos and they said there is a **Theme Options** section has the social links, but I do not have a Theme Options. Are there any ideas to find the social links part? 
Thank you,

[image: Wordpress Follow information]

[image: Apperance]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Haha I found it!It is under the "Web Page Design".

[image: Social Links]